# Is enumerating/looping through an array of 200+ objects slow

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray, nsdictionary, enumeration

Before I actually test it out, I want to know this.

I have a plist with 210 dictionaries, and in my code I initialize an `NSArray` through the contents of that plist.

Out of all these dictionaries, I need to enumerate through them and check for something:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in largePlistArray) {

if ([[dict objectForKey: @"country"] isEqualToString: @"Cambodia"]) {

 NSLog (@"Random example!");

   }

 }
```

Let us say the dictionary with 'Cambodia' is the last in the whole array, how long will it take to enumerate through an full 200+ object array of dictionaries?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the size of your plist?  210 actual dictionaries could take quite a while (computationally speaking).

Comment: 210 actual dictionaries with 5 strings in each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to tell is to try it out. However, `200` does not strike me as a particularly large or even as a marginally large number. Consider this: 1GHz CPU runs a billion elementary operations per second. Even if each lookup takes 100 elementary operations (in reality, it takes much fewer than that) a search of `200` items should complete in very short time, on the order of milliseconds.

Comment: Wow, that never striked me, I thought 200 would take a second or a few! Thanks a lot!

Comment: For a very quick check, you put an NSLog before and after the loop. NSLog displays the time. To get better measurements, do the same loop ten times, then 100 times, and so on until it gets slow.